# Is there a more efficient way to write this if (or) statement?

Tags: lua

I'm looking to make sure that it is/isn't possible to write this statement more efficiently in Lua:

```
if (value == 1 or value == 2) then
```

something like this for an example (nonworking I assume):

```
if (value == (1 or 2)) then
```

or

```
if value == (1;2) then
```

Comment: `if ({0,0})[value] then`, but I guess it is more slowly as compared with two equalities (even if the table was created beforehand: `if t[value] then`).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yes, bcuz of lookup.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the produced bytecode as a proxy for speed.  (Microbenchmarks are *not* reliable.  Caching, pipelinging, branch prediction, … can have *really* weird effects that can make code that *should* be slower in principle perform better in practice *in the context where you're actually using it*.  Bytecode size also isn't a very good indicator (same problems apply), but at least it's easy to produce, deterministic, and easy to interpret.)

(To follow along, throw your test files at `luac -p -l`, which will only `p`arse (not write a compiled file) and `l`ist the resulting bytecode as a side-effect.  If you want to understand the bytecode, have a look at the [unofficial bytecode reference](https://the-ravi-programming-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lua_bytecode_reference.html) as initially created by Kein-Hong Man and kindly updated by Dibyendu Majumdar.  But you don't have to.)

If `value` is a global variable, you'll get this:

```lisp
1   [1] GETTABUP   0 0 -1 ; _ENV "value"
2   [1] EQ         1 0 -2 ; - 1   (fall through to next comparison)
3   [1] JMP        0 3    ; to 7  (true branch)
4   [1] GETTABUP   0 0 -1 ; _ENV "value"
5   [1] EQ         0 0 -3 ; - 2   (fall through into true branch)
6   [1] JMP        0 1    ; to 8  (beyond true branch)
```

Translating back into "pseudo-Lua", this is rougly

```
local r0 = _ENV["value"]
if r0 == 1 then  goto true_branch  end
local r0 = _ENV["value"]
if r0 ~= 2 then  goto fin  end
::true_branch::
-- stuff here
::fin::
```

If `value` is `local` (or a function argument) in the function where you use this, then you'll get something like this instead:

```lisp
1   [1] EQ         1 0 -1 ; - 1
2   [1] JMP        0 2    ; to 5
3   [1] EQ         0 0 -2 ; - 2
4   [1] JMP        0 1    ; to 6
```

or roughly

```
if r0 == 1 then  goto true_branch  end
if r0 ~= 2 then  goto fin  end
::true_branch::
-- stuff here
::fin::
```

"Much" better!

So if `value` is a global variable (or an upvalue), doing

```
local value = value
if value == 1 or value == 2 then
  -- stuff
end
```

will give you

```lisp
1   [1] GETTABUP   0 0 -1 ; _ENV "value"
2   [1] EQ         1 0 -2 ; - 1
3   [1] JMP        0 2    ; to 6
4   [1] EQ         0 0 -3 ; - 2
5   [1] JMP        0 1    ; to 7
```

or

```
local r0 = _ENV["value"]
if r0 == 1 then  goto true_branch  end
if r0 == 2 then  goto true_branch  end
goto fin
::true_branch::
-- stuff here
::fin::
```

which saves one lookup.  (While microbenchmarks will show a clear difference, *in practice* you'll almost never notice a difference.  If you're doing a deeper lookup `if foo.bar.baz == 1 or foo.bar.baz == 2 then` it makes sense to `local` first, and it will probably also increase readability.)